# Timing com setInterval em JS

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Galera estou tentando fazer um timer, ate está funcionando o problema é que ele so diminui o tempo se eu ficar clicando, e eu preciso que ele dimiua sozinho apos eu clicar uma vez.

```js
  var mins = "30";
  var secs = "00";

function timeCount(){
  if (secs == "00"){
      secs = "60";
      mins -= 1;
    }
  
  i = 0;
    do {
      secs -= 01;
      i++;
    }
    while(i < secs.length);
  
  if (secs < "10"){
    secs = "0" + secs +"";
  }
   if (mins == "0"){
    console.log("acabou");
  }
  
  time = ''+ mins + ':' + secs + '';
      $("#time").html(time);
      console.log(time);
}
```

```html
<div id="timer" onclick="setTimeout(timeCount, 3000)">
  <span id="time">30:00</span>
</div>
```

Se alguem puder me da uma mão ai eu agradeço. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema do seu código é que você está usando o setTimeout. Tente modificar para o setInterval que vai funcionar. Ah... Outra coisa, se está querendo fazer um timer, seria mais interessande se o intervalo do setInterval fose 1000.

Referências:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Exemplo de como ficaria o seu código:

```js
var mins = "30";
var secs = "00";

function timeCount() {
  if (secs == "00") {
    secs = "60";
    mins -= 1;
  }

  i = 0;
  do {
    secs -= 01;
    i++;
  }
  while (i < secs.length);

  if (secs < "10") {
    secs = "0" + secs + "";
  }
  if (mins == "0") {
    console.log("acabou");
  }

  time = '' + mins + ':' + secs + '';
  $("#time").html(time);
  console.log(time);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="timer" onclick="setInterval(timeCount, 1000)">
        <span id="time">30:00</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Vlw cara era isso mesmo o/

Answer (score 0):

Podes fazer assim:

```js
    function pad(s) {
        return (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s;
    }
    
    function cronometro(segundos) {
        var seg = segundos % 60;
        var min = Math.floor(segundos / 60);
        document.getElementById('contador').innerHTML = [min, seg].map(pad).join(':');
        if (segundos > 0) setTimeout(cronometro, 1000, segundos - 1);
    }
    
    cronometro(180);
```

```html
<div id="contador"></div>
```

Dessa maneira passas o numero de segundos à função e ela vai contando...

Se quiseres fazer ao clicar em algo podes fazer assim: https://jsfiddle.net/rbn988uy/