# Relógio que decrementa rápido demais

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web, front-end

Estou tentando fazer um contador funcionar quando eu clico num botão, acontece que quando botão é clicado **mais de uma vez** o contador começa a decrementar rápido demais.

**Código fonte:**

```js
var pomodoro = document.querySelector('#btn1');


    var count = new Number();
    
    function start () {
        if((count -1) >= 0) {
            count = count - 1;
            sessao.innerText = count;
            setTimeout('start()', 1000);
        }
    }
    
    pomodoro.onclick = function () {
        count = 1500;
        return start();
    }
```

[Aqui tá o link de um vídeo de 30 segundos mostrando como o código tá funcionando.](https://youtu.be/r-q9drAbGHw)

Comment: Você quer então que isso seja chamado uma vez somente e que possa parar ? (porque acontece tal comportamente citado: o código está sendo chamado várias vezes e ai acaba tendo o incremento várias vezes e a sua impressão é que isso está acontecendo rapido de mais). Qual o comportamento esperado para seu código

Comment: Opa, Virgilio, bom dia. A minha intenção é que, ao clicar novamente, ele reinicie a contangem normalmente, sem decrementar muito rápido, como está acontecendo aí.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Então utilize [setInterval](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129826/timing-com-setinterval-em-js) que pode parar e depois reiniciar com [clearInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp), ou seja, um cria o temporizador e outro para, **exemplo**:

```js
const pomodoro = document.querySelector('#btn1');
const source = document.getElementById("source");
let count = new Number();
let stopEvent = null;

function start () {
    if((count -1) >= 0) {
        count = count - 1; 
        source.innerHTML = count;
    }
    else 
    {
      if (stopEvent) {
        clearInterval(stopEvent);
      }
    }
}

pomodoro.onclick = function () {
    count = 1501;
    if (stopEvent) {
      clearInterval(stopEvent);
    }
    stopEvent = setInterval('start()', 1000);    
}
```

```html
<p id="source"></p>
<button id="btn1">Iniciar</button>
```

Foi implementado bem simples para o seu entendimento, pode refatorar algumas coisas, mas, a intenção principal é entender que com [setInterval](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129826/timing-com-setinterval-em-js) pode parar e reiniciar quando quiser, a outra forma fica chamando em um processo ruim não tem como parar até o momento da função não ser mais invocada.

Comment: Funcionou, valeu, cara.

Comment: @Maggrilmur se for útil vote aceita como resposta da sua pergunta